# Golang example of using google.golang.org/api/discovery/v1

Tags: go, google-cloud-sdk

I am trying to use the Go discovery to make a call to an API that doesn't have client libraries yet. But I cannot find an example.

The goal is to replace using the net/http:

```
func AnotherFunc() {
// get short-lived oauth access token so we can make authenticated API call
    accessToken, _ := getOauthAccessToken()

    client := &http.Client{}
    rolesQueryString := ""
    for _, r := range configs.CustomOwnerRoles {
        rolesQueryString += "analysisQuery.accessSelector.roles=" +
            url.QueryEscape(r) + "&"
    }
    // documentation for this api call can be found here:
    // https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/reference/rest/v1p4beta1/TopLevel/analyzeIamPolicy
    // we're making a REST api call instead of using client libraries because this is a new
    // API, and the client libraries haven't been generated for it yet.
    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "https://cloudasset.googleapis.com/v1p4beta1/"+
        configs.OrganizationID+
        ":analyzeIamPolicy?"+
        rolesQueryString+
        "&analysisQuery.identitySelector.identity="+
        url.QueryEscape("user:"+user)+
        "&analysisQuery.resourceSelector.fullResourceName="+
        url.QueryEscape("//cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/projects/"+projectID)+
        "&options.expandGroups=true", nil)
}
```

I want to use the discovery library, but only got this far:

```
    api := flag.String("api", "cloudasset", "api to query")
    resource := flag.String("resource", "", "resource to generate")
    version := flag.String("version", "v1p4beta1", "api version to query")
    flag.Parse()

    if *api == "" || *resource == "" {
        flag.PrintDefaults()
        log.Fatal("usage: go run schemagen.go -api $API -resource $RESOURCE -version $VERSION")
    }

    ctx := context.Background()
    discoveryService, err := discovery.NewService(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(fmt.Errorf("Error creating service: %v", err))
    }

    resp, err := discoveryService.Apis.GetRest(*api, *version).Fields("schemas").Do()
```

How do I use `resp` to continue with the API call?

Answer (score 0):

I've looked for samples on the usage of the discovery API with go and I could see that there's basically nothing easily usable.

I've found a [Medium article](https://medium.com/@masnun/making-http-requests-in-golang-dd123379efe7) with some guidance to consume RESTFUL API resources such as the [Cloud Discovery Service](https://developers.google.com/discovery/).

I think the answer it's that you need to call the resp.Body.Close() to assure that the resources are handled properly, later in the samples there are a couple of ways to get the data, so you would have to add something like this:

```
defer resp.Body.Close()
body, err := http.ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
if err ≠ nil {
    log.Failure(err)
}
log.Println(string(body))
```

Comment: Do you have a full example? e.g. list IAM role or list something

Comment: I was looking more carefully and I could see that after the execution the resp variable should be the response object, and such object should have this [form](https://developers.google.com/discovery/v1/reference/apis#resource)